# Vuejs can't get data in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this code:

```
let data = res.data.data;

console.log('data: ', data)

const list = [];
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    console.log('data i: ', data[i]) //not printing in console
    list.push({
        lat: data[i].latitude,
        lng: data[i].longitude,
        histories: data[i].histories,
    })

    lineString.pushPoint({
        lat:data[i].longitude, 
        lng:data[i].latitude
    })
}
console.log('list: ', list)
```

It return results as:

[image: one]

As you can see in my `data` part I have all results but in `list` part I get nothing!

**Why I can't get my filtered data into list array?**

Comment: Code looks pretty much correct to me. Maybe that's all executed asynchronously and `data` isn't set at that given point. A minimal example repo might help here.

Comment: @Aer0 `A minimal example repo might help here` what's repo? what should i do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Well your `data` isnt an array, its an object so you need to loop over an object. The curly brace, blue marked on the image, indicates that its an object.

```
for(let prop in data){
   if(prop == "histories") continue;
   list.push({
      lat: data[prop].latitude,
      lng: data[prop].longitude,
      histories: data["histories"]
   })
}
```

Comment: @mafortis please take a look i have updated it. its now cleaner

Comment: well `data["histories"][prop]` prop part is not needed (it returns error as there is no history prop in my data) and if condition also not needed i simply just pass some of my data into new array nothing about validating here :) and thank you for update

Comment: no the last line was ok, just `[prop]` part wasn't needed.

Comment: like this is ok: `histories: data["histories"]`